# Can guice inject dependencies which have @SuperBuilder annotation?

Tags: guice, lombok

I have a class which has a dependency `List<BaseClass>`.

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
Class A {
  List<BaseClass> list;
}
```

Now, I also have two childClasses extending this base class. To each of these child classes and the base class, I have added the Lombok's @SuperBuiler annotation

```
@SuperBuilder
Class ChildClass1 extends BaseClass {
    DependencyA depA;
}

@SuperBuilder
Class ChildClass1 extends BaseClass {
    DependencyB depB;
}

@SuperBuilder
abstract Class BaseClass {
    final DependencyC depC;
}
```

I have written a method for injecting the List in a guice module which takes in these two child class objects.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public List<BaseClass> getObjects(ChildClass1 c1, ChildClass2 c2) {
     return Arrays.asList(c1, c2);
}
```

I want to know if Guice can resolve these child class ojects or do I need to write methods for providing these ?

Comment: Please provide some code to have your problem easier to understand. Anyway, assuming that Guice can do that, with which values your object should be built, how Guice would know it?

Comment: I ran the service(it failed) and found out that I needed to write provider method as guice needs constructors in order to inject the dependencies. The constructors are not accessible as @SuperBuilder makes them protected while exposing a static builder() method which can take in the properties of the base and child class(in the form of a chain)  in one go.

Comment: I don't think Guice can do that. But you could possibly leverage field injection with no-args constructors (at least package-private).

Comment: The only issue with that is the field in the base class is a final field. So, can't use the no args constructor.

Comment: So probably the best option could be to use Guice’s @Provides binding - but you will need to build your objects  manually.